# Exclamation mark behind assigned value: A = B ! C

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I am reading piece of company javaScript cods and I found the following:

```
seriesCode = pageRecord.getProperty('seriesCode')!'XXX'
```

Does this mean that if first value is `NULL` the second on should be placed in seriesCode?

Comment: Looks invalid to me...

Comment: maybe it should be `||`

Comment: You should get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'".

Comment: actually, there is no error, and I am reading somebody else codes. Maybe it's freemarker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like FreeMarker template language, and yes, the `!` operator, when appears on the right side of an operand gives a default value if the left side expression is `null` or a reference to a missing variable.

Answer (score 2):

well, your code is wrong and cannot be parsed. You might even get a weird not understandable error.

> Does it mean that if first value is `NULL` the second on should be placed in `seriesCode`?

no, it's just *wrong* and cannot be understood by javascript. `!` is a unary operator, so it's likely to fail in weird ways if you try to use it as a binary operator (in between two values).

What you're asking is done using the `||` operator:

```
seriesCode = pageRecord.getProperty('seriesCode')||'XXX';
```

you might see a trick with the `!` unary operator, though being the double exclamation mark:

```
existsSeriesCode = !!pageRecord.getProperty('seriesCode');
```

the idea here is that with the first exclamation mark, you're converting your object into a boolean, where `false` means this variable is a reference to an instance, and `true` means the variable contains either `null` or `undefined`. Then the second exclamation mark is there to negate it again, meaning that `true` contains an instance, `false` contains either `undefined` or `null`.